# Allow text selection in Bootstrap table

Tags: css, text, selection, onclicklistener, bootstrap-table

Initially, it was completely impossible to select any text from my bootstrap table. At first, I focused on CSS and found a very partial solution using

> webkit-select-user

Later on, I noticed that the table has an onClickRow event defined. When I removed it, text selection worked normally and I could copy text from the table. 
My problem is, obviously, that I need to keep the event handler and still make text selection possible.

Comment: Add some codes to support your question.

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to give out a solution without a code to work with but have you tried `pointer-events: none;`

More info: [pointer-events](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp).

Comment: I tried adding it in several places but to no avail. Sorry about the lack of code, I can't seem to make a simple fiddle exanple to show the problem. I guess my project and the table itself are too complex and large so I can't point out how to recreate the issue.

Comment: Hm, what you can do is do an EventHandler event and just alert or console the target. Maybe that can help you figure out the problem. Without code I can't help you. I assume their is something wrong in the code itself.